# process.env.CONNECT_DATABASE is undefined while console.log

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, dotenv

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

require("dotenv").config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./.env") });

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

console.log(process.env.DB_CONNECT);
// mongoose.connect(
//   process.env.DB_CONNECT,
//   { useNewUrlParse: true },

//   () => console.log("connected to db!")
// );

    const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
    
    app.use("/api/user", authRoute);
    
    app.listen(3000, () => console.log("serve is up"));



const router = require("express").Router();

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Register");
});

// router.post("/login");

module.exports = router;





DB_CONNECT="mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@fypdatabase.quhdl.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

I have installed mongoose, express, dotenv. I tried to connect user to the data base using dotenv, without dotenv it was working perfeclty fine:

moongoose.connect("url",{useNewUrlParser:true},console.log('connected');

But when I tried with dotenv and consolo logging the process.env.DB_CONNECT to see if there is value or not and it is showing undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

dotenv.config();

// console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL);

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGO_URL,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  () => {
    console.log('database connected');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you specified wrong path to the `.env` file. Try to put `.env` file in the root of your application. Then just use `config()` without `path` option. `.env` package will by default check it for you in the root of the application.

```
require("dotenv").config();
```